# Decode H264 stream and convert to BitmapSource?

Tags: ffmpeg, rgb, h.264, yuv, bitmapsource

I'm using `FFMPEG` to decode `H264` stream.

The result in the output frame is `AVFrame* pFrame`, its format may be `YUV420P`.

I want to convert `pFrame` to `RGB` and then construct `BimapSource` from that`RGB`.

I have searched on the internet, there are many ways to convert from `pFrame` to `RGB`.

But the final output that I need is `BitmapSource` of `C#`. So I don't know which way is better?

Someone can show me the algorithm that convert `pFrame -> RGB -> BitmapSource`.

The performance is very important for this stage, so I need the fastest algorithm.

Many Thanks,

T&T!